# What is difference between these approaches in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First approach

```
n, m = [int(n), int(m)]
```

Second approach

```
n, m = int(n), int(m)
```

Both lines gives the same output. Then, is it necessary to close parameters under square bracket?

Comment: Which part makes you think it is necessary if the output is the same?

Comment: in the first you're unpacking a list, in the second you're unpacking a tuple

Comment: why the down votes? it's a genuine question.

Comment: @mga basic questions tend to not get a lot of love, especially if they don't show an attempt to find the answer. This question relates to not understanding [tuple assignment](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html#tuple-assignment) and that `int(n), int(m)` is in implicit, rather than explicit tuple.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Except for empty tuples, tuples are formed by comma operators, not parentheses. `a,b` is an explicit tuple display.  `(a,b)` is a tuple set off from other code by parentheses.   https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms

Answer (score 2):

`int(n), int(m)` creates a 2-item tuple. `[int(n), int(m)]` creates a 2-item list.  Once you break the pair apart into 2 items, as part of the assignments, there is no difference left.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach creates a list and the second one - a tuple. When this 2 variables are apart there is no difference